# .anyRequest().authenticated() problema desde el frontend

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Tengo un problema a la hora de cargar imagenes desde el FrontEnd, en las siguientes lineas de codigo:

```
<img (click)="abrirModal(cliente)" *ngIf="cliente?.foto" src="http://localhost:8080/api/uploads/img/{{cliente.foto}}" alt="{{cliente.foto}}" class="img-thumbnail rounded" style="width: 64px; cursor: pointer;">
              <img (click)="abrirModal(cliente)" *ngIf="!cliente?.foto" src="http://localhost:8080/images/no-user.png" alt="sin-foto" class="img-thumbnail rounded" style="width: 64px; cursor: pointer;">
```

Revisando lo que sucede me di cuenta que `.anyRequest().authenticated()` en mi configuración me solicita autenticación para mostrar las imagenes (solo las imagenes, ya que el resto del contenido que solicito ya es validado en el `requestMatchers`).

```
@Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authManager) throws Exception {

        JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
        jwtAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        jwtAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");

        return http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("api/**")
                .authenticated()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
```

yo desde el frontend envio mi bearer token para validar, por eso no tengo problema con la informacion solicitada en las direcciones api/**, pero no se como hacerlo para las direcciones que pido en el html. Espero me puedan ayudar! estare atento y muchas gracias!

PD: no coloco `permitAll()` en `.anyRequest().authenticated()` ya que cualquier persona que tenga o encuentra la Url sin estar autenticado puede verla. Claro colocando eso ya me funcionaba perfectamente.

Comment: lo que pasa es que solamente le estas dando acceso a tu api y mas no a la imagen , tienes que asignar a tus imagenes tbm un permiso all

Answer (score 0):

A partir de Spring Security 5.7 puedes agregar un **Bean** `WebSecurityCustomizer`, que es una interfaz funcional para configurar el filter chain que ya definiste, de la siguiente forma:

```
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**");
    }
```

Esto podría estar en la misma clase donde defines `filterChain`.

Puedes leer más en el siguiente [artículo](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deprecated-websecurityconfigureradapter)

**Actualización**
A partir de Spring Security 6 (que viene con Spring Boot 3), como bien acota @PabloLozano, no se usa más `antMatchers` sino `requestMatchers`, La solución anterior(que sirve para Spring Boot 2.7), quedaría de la siguiente forma para Spring Security 6:

```
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/images/**");
    }
```

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, `antMatchers` está marcado como *Deprecated*, ahora (Spring Boot 3) se ha de usar `requestMatchers`

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609057/how-to-fix-spring-authorizerequests-is-deprecated, saludos.

Comment: @PabloLozano, más que deprecado es undefined para Spring Security 6 (que es lo que viene con Spring Boot 3. La respuesta sirve para Spring Boot 2.7 y superior. Veo que en el código de la pregunta se usa `requestMatchers`, así que actualizo la respuesta. Muy buena observación!

Comment: @PabloLozano, Gracias y funciona, pero aun asi es como un permit all, fuera de mi aplicacion puedo colocar el enlace a la imagen que previamente coloque y accesde sin ningun problema. Esa es la capa de proteccion que quiero cubrir